# Not all tick labels are shown when using xtick=data

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw the following plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0, ymax=90,
            width=5.5cm,
            height=6cm,
            symbolic x coords={A,B},
            xtick=data,
            bar width=15pt,
            axis lines*=left,
            ytick={10,30,...,90},
            nodes near coords,
            xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
            ymajorgrids,
            enlarge x limits=.3,
            ]
            \addplot[fill=red] coordinates {
                (A,16.6)
            };
            \addplot[fill=green] coordinates {
                (B,23.9)
                };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However it does not seem to work out: the second xtick coordinate (B) doesn't show up.

What I want is to have a simple plot with two or more bars each with a different color.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `xtick=data`, only the first `\addplot` command is used to determine the tick positions. To get both tick labels, use `xtick={A,B}`.

By default, PGFPlots assumes that each `\addplot` series will have values at the same coordinates, which is why the bars for each series are offset to prevent overlap. In your special case of all `\addplot` commands using different coordinates, that's not desired. To switch off this shift, set set `bar shift=0pt`.

Comment: now the B is there but the tick isn't centered under the bar. Is there a way to center it?

Comment: @Julia: I've edited my answer.